# Veterans appealing against politicization of the army

Tags: india

Recently, veterans of the Indian army had written a letter to the President of India [complaining about the politicization of the army](https://thewire.in/security/veterans-ask-president-to-urge-parties-to-stop-using-military-for-political-gains) and its operations. The ruling government had denied about this and called it a hoax but [its claim was debunked](https://thewire.in/media/ani-veterans-appeal-president-proof) and the letter was found to be true.

Has it ever happened in independent India where the patriotic feelings associated with the army has been misused by political parties to make inroads among the general population?

Comment: The Wire is known for its left wing bias (https://mediabiasfactcheck.com/the-wire-india/). Do you have any other reliable unbiased sources to debunk the claim?

Comment: The given source may have a leftist bias, but they have very clearly given proof of what has happened. Agreed, their style of writing may be provocative, but the core of the issue remains the same. So unless you have any serious objections/information that the subject in the source is fake, I guess this will do.